# Kotlin, delete all items in list with isChecked property equal to true

Tags: android, kotlin

New to Android dev here, and this might be very basic but I have the following data class in Kotlin

```
data class ABC(val: id: String, val isChecked: Boolean = false)
```

and the following mutable list in a separate ClassB:

```
ABC_multiple: MutableList<ABC>
```

And I have the following button in the main activity of my app:

```
removeButton.setOnClickListener { classb.removeId() }
```

I would like the button to delete all of the list items that are checked (each item that will be added to the mutablelist has its own separate isChecked property)

I cannot seem to find a way to get the isChecked property to change and verified this by adding a button to run the following code:

```
System.out.println(ListItem + isChecked)
```

Clicking shows the isChecked property does not change whether any particular item in the list is checked or unchecked

Would really appreciate any help

Comment: `list.removeAll { it.isChecked }`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that. You can check this [link](https://www.techiedelight.com/conditionally-remove-elements-list-kotlin/)